# cascading comboboxes in wpf datagrid using entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using combo boxes in data template column (not datagridcomboboxcolumn) using entity framework model. In first column of datagrid. combobox should display countries and in second coloumn the combobox should display states. when country is changed in a row the states in second column combo must be updated as per country in that row. I have three tables viz country(country_id int,country_name) , state(country_id, state_id , state_name), and district(country_id, state_id ,district_id, district_name). I have four .cs files as

**1:testEntities.cs**

```
public partial class testEntities : DbContext
{
    public testEntities()
        : base("name=testEntities")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
    public DbSet<country> countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<district> districts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<state> states { get; set; }
}
```

**2:-country.cs **

```
public partial class country
{
    public byte country_id { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
}
```

**3:-state.cs**

```
public partial class state
{
    public Nullable<byte> country_id { get; set; }
    public byte state_id { get; set; }
    public string state_name { get; set; }
}
```

**4:-district.cs**

```
public partial class district
{
    public Nullable<byte> country_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> state_id { get; set; }
    public byte district_id { get; set; }
    public string district_name { get; set; }
}
```

and one xaml file

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="countryViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:country},CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="statetViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:state}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="districtViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:district}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid >
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              DataContext="{StaticResource districtViewSource}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="47,45,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Height="179" Width="421">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country" SortMemberPath="country_id" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding country_name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                  DataContext="{StaticResource countryViewSource}" 
                                  SelectedValue ="{Binding country_id, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="country_name" SelectedValuePath="country_id" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State" SortMemberPath="state_id">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding state_name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                                  DataContext="{StaticResource statetViewSource}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="state_name"
                                  SelectedValuePath="state_id"
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding state_id, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="district_idColumn" Binding="{Binding district_id}" Header="district id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="district_nameColumn" Binding="{Binding district_name}" Header="district name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

the code behind xaml is lot of thanks in advance

```
using System.Windows.Data;
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    testEntities te= new testEntities ();
    CollectionViewSource countryViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("countryViewSource")));
    CollectionViewSource stateViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("stateViewSource")));
    CollectionViewSource districtViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("districtViewSource")));

    te.countries .Load();
    te.states .Load ();
    te.districts .Load ();

    countryViewSource.Source = te.countries.Local;
    stateViewSource.Source = te.states.Local;
    districtViewSource.Source = te.countries.Local;
}
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hello , thanks for reply of my question cascading cb in datagrid but it is not working. May i know your email so that i could send full code thnaks my email nirankar.kaushik@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start
If states are in a county then put them in the country

```
public partial class country
{
    public byte country_id { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public DbSet<state> states { get; set; }
}
```

Then in cbStates binding use syntax like this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbCountries, Path=SelectedItem.States}"
```